# How to create super user in Postgres

Tags: postgresql

I am new to Saleor and I followed all the step in the documentation. However I can't seem to create a new user. I have install PostgreSQL 11 using a .dmg file downloaded from the official website.
Every time I run `createuser --superuser --pwprompt <username>` I get `bash: createuser: command not found`.
If I try to install PostgreSQL with "brew install Postgres" and then run `createuser --superuser --pwprompt <username>`, I get asked for password twice for the new role then a third time which I have tried to many time to enter with no success. I get the error `FATAL: password authentication failed for user <terminal username>`.
I'm using VS code

Comment: You have to run `createuser` as a user that already has superuser access. The installation should have created a `postgres` user (in the operating system) that can run it. You could use `sudo` or a similar tool to run that command from that user account.

Comment: Thank you very much. Sudo isn't working I had to change users